# Diferenciar sesiones PHP entre sistemas

Tags: php, login, session

Me he encontrado con el siguiente problema.

2 sistemas montados con PHP y manejo del acceso a traves de la creación de sesiones en el momento del login.

Al momento de ingresar a uno de los sistemas, automaticamente me habilita tambien el ingreso al otro sistema, logro entender que es porque en cada uno levanto y permito el acceso consultando si la variable de `$_Session['usuario']` ha sido seteada.

Mi consulta es, **¿cómo puede lograr crear sesiones distintas para cada sistema si estos se ejecutan simultaneamente?**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las sesiones en PHP se identifican por las `cookies` y depende del valor de estas cada que se hace una petición. Si tu script no tiene un [nombre de sesión](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-name.php) entonces todos tus scripts usarán el mismo nombre de sesión para todos los scripts y si estos encima, están en el mismo dominio, entonces PHP continuará la sesión anterior sin problema alguno.

En el manejo de sesiones de cada uno de tus sistemas necesitas usar algo como:

```
session_name('sistema_alpha');
session_start();
```

Esto debe estar siempre antes de `session_start()`, de esta manera al iniciar sesión en el sistema 1 el sistema 2 no iniciará sesión porque buscará la cookie "sistema_beta" para revisar si es válida y así resumir o denegar la sesión:

```
session_name('sistema_beta');
session_start();
```

Comment: En efecto, tu comentario resulto ser la solución al manejo de sesiones para diferentes sistemas hospedados en un mismo dominio, muchas gracias!!!